# How do I combine similar elements in a list in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, image-processing, color-palette

As a practice exercise, I'm trying to generate a color pallette from an image, and am using Python to turn the raw extracted RGB channels into a pallette. This is fairly simple using a combination of lists and dictionaries, but I'd like to be able to put a constraint the the number of colors in the pallette by combining similar color channels, unless they both have a large presence in the image.

Say I have a dictionary with my RGB values and their counts:

```
countsR = {"255": 301, "250": 16, "10": 589, "14": 124, "8": 132}
```

This pallette requires 3 bits to index into. Ideally I would run some function, `combine_channels(dd, max_distance)`, which does some terrible `O(N^2)` things, and outputs something like this:

```
print(combine_channels(countsR, 10))
>>> {"255": 317, "10": 845}
```

Which now may be indexed by only one bit!

It would also be good if it could keep track of which things it replaced with what, maybe in another dictionary:

```
countsR, replacements = combine_channels(countsR, 10)
print(replacements)
>>> {"255": ["250"], "10": ["8", "14"]}
```

Any ideas on what this may look like?

Comment: How would this work in case there are multiple options for combination? Let's say `countsR  = {"5": 10, "10": 20, "15": 30, "20": 40, "25": 50, "30": 60}` what would be expected result for `combine_channels(countsR, 10)`?

Comment: Maximum diversity; so the resulting entries are maximally distant from each other. The more I describe it, the more it sounds like something that might be NP-hard.

Comment: Still bit ambiguous, what would be the keys in the result? 5 & 25 or 10 & 30? In case of former which one would `"15": 30` be combined to?

Comment: Given the maximally distant condition, it would be 5 & 25. That's a good question on the 15. If there's an equal split, we could share the counts evenly between the two equidistant groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases there's multiple different grouping options as the comments show. One easy option is to iterate through channels in numerical order forming groups and if a channel can't be fitted to existing group create a new one. It won't result to maximal distance but it will guarantee minimum number of groups to be generated:

```
def combine_channels(channels, dist):
    result = {}
    replacements = {}
    groups = []
    group = []
    key = None

    # Iterate through channels in ascending numerical order
    for channel, count in sorted((int(k), v) for k, v in channels.items()):
        # Add new group in case that channel doesn't fit to current group
        if group and channel - key > dist:
            groups.append((key, group))
            group = []
            key = None

        # Add channel to group
        group.append((channel, count))

        # Pick a new key in case there's none or current channel is within
        # dist from first channel in the group
        if key is None or channel - group[0][0] <= dist:
            key = channel

    # Add last group in case it exists
    if group:
        groups.append((key, group))

    for key, group in groups:
        result[key] = sum(x[1] for x in group)
        replacements[key] = [x[0] for x in group if x[0] != key]

    return result, replacements

countsR1 = {"255": 301, "250": 16, "10": 589, "14": 124, "8": 132}
countsR2 = {"0": 10, "11": 20, "7": 30, "19": 40, "25": 50}
countsR3 = {"0": 5, "11": 10}
print(combine_channels(countsR1, 10))
print(combine_channels(countsR2, 10))
print(combine_channels(countsR3, 10))
```

Output:

```
({14: 845, 255: 317}, {14: [8, 10], 255: [250]})
({25: 90, 7: 60}, {25: [19], 7: [0, 11]})
({0: 5, 11: 10}, {0: [], 11: []})
```

Time complexity of above is **O(n log n)** since sorting is used.

Comment: I think we did something similar. Care to take a look at my own attempt?

Comment: By the way, this worked amazingly in my pallette generator! I cna't thank you enough :) Any way you could explain what that takewhile bit does and all the lambdas?

Comment: @ijustlovemath When starting to explain about the `takewhile` I realized that the previous implementation incorrectly grouped channels in the third test case I added. There's not much point of explaining what isn't there any more but if you have questions about the current version let me know.

Comment: Ah okay! Well the prior version actually worked wonderfully in my application, though I'll be replacing it with this one since it's one less module dependency. What was wrong with it that it failed your third test?

Comment: @ijustlovemath The original version incorrectly assumed that that `0` & `11` could be under the same group if `dist = 10`. This is not the case if there's no channels in between of those two.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
def combine_channels(lst, max_dist):
    colors = list(set(lst)) # unique colors
    counts = dict()
    replacements = dict()
    all_repl = []

    for el in lst:
        counts[el] = counts.get(el, 0) + 1

    N = len(colors)
    dists = np.zeros((N, N))
    for i in range(N - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, N):
            dist = abs(colors[i] - colors[j])
            dists[i, j] = dist
            if(dist < max_dist):
                if(colors[i] in all_repl or colors[j] in all_repl):
                    continue
                else:
                    if(counts.get(colors[i], 0) > counts.get(colors[j], 0)):
                        winner = colors[i]
                        loser = colors[j]
                    else:
                        winner = colors[j]
                        loser = colors[i]
                counts[winner] += counts.get(loser, 0)
                counts[loser] = 0
                if winner not in replacements:
                    replacements[winner] = list()
                replacements[winner].append(loser)
                all_repl.append(loser)
                if loser not in replacements:
                    continue
                else:
                    replacements[winner] = replacements[winner].extend(replacements[loser])
                    replacements.pop(loser, None)              
    print(replacements)
```

There's probably many more efficient ways to do it, and it doesn't satisfy the maximum distance requirement, but it works!

Comment: Since there's two nested loops and `in` operator is used for `list` in inner one the complexity is **O(n^3)**. `replacements[winner] = replacements[winner].extend(replacements[loser])` is a bug since `list.extend` does not return anything. Also input `{5: 1, 11: 2, 15: 3, 20: 4}` results to incorrect output `{20: [11, 15]}`.